# Flutter rounded profile image appBar

Tags: dart, flutter

I'm currently new to Flutter and Dart language and I'm trying to set a profile image to my leading attribute of my appBar.

So far I've got my image to be rounded, but I can't make it smaller nor put a margin to the left side.

Here's a snippet of my code:

```
@override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new MaterialApp(
      home: new Scaffold(
        backgroundColor: Colors.blueGrey,
        appBar: new AppBar(
          title: new Text("Activities"),
          leading: new Container(
            padding: new EdgeInsets.all(15.0),
            width: 10.0,
            height: 10.0,
            decoration: new BoxDecoration(
              color: const Color(0xff7c94b6),
              borderRadius: new BorderRadius.all(new Radius.circular(50.0)),
              border: new Border.all(
                color: Colors.white,
                width: 1.0,
              ),
            ),
          ),
          actions: <Widget>[
            new IconButton(
              icon: new Icon(Icons.refresh),
              onPressed: () {
                print("Reloading...");
                setState(() {
                  _isLoading = true;
                });
                _FetchData();
              },
            )
          ],
        ),
```

// ...

And here's how it looks:
[Click here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yUMVz.jpg)

As you can see, my image is way too big and there's no margin to the left side...

How can I make the image smaller and most importantly, make a left margin similar to the refresh button right's margin?

Any help would be appreciated,
Have a good one.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Consider using `Material` combined with a `shape: new CircleBorder()` instead of manually creating a circle. 
Or a [`CircleAvatar`](https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/material/CircleAvatar-class.html) if that fits your needs.

Then add a `Padding` to control the size and margin.

```
return new Scaffold(
  backgroundColor: Colors.blueGrey,
  appBar: new AppBar(
    title: new Text("Activities"),
    leading: new Padding(
      padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
      child: new Material(
        shape: new CircleBorder(),
      ),
    ),
  ),
);
```

[image]

Comment: Merci Rémi c'est exactement ce que j'voulais!

Comment: yes, CircleAvatar would be more convenient and easy.

Comment: I took this solution...Thanks

Comment: But unable to add image in the circle?!